# Drag and drop from Winforms to outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, drag

How can I drag and drop a file from a winforms app (I have a grid that has the path to the file) into outlook? Outlook will grab that file and add it as an attachment.

I've seen how to drag and drop into the windows explorer but I cannot make it work in outlook.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494400/drag-a-file-url-from-a-winforms-control-to-external-application).